Error: The required parameter 'channelID' is empty. Rerun the command with -C flag
for below command
peer chaincode invoke -o localhost:7050 --ordererTLSHostnameOverride orderer.example.com --tls $CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED --cafile $ORDERER_CA -C ${CHANNEL_NAME} -n ${CC_NAME} --peerAddresses localhost:10051 --tlsRootCertFiles $PEER1_ORG2_CA -c '{"function": "createCar", "Args":["CAR103","AudiX","R8","Black", "CM"]}'

Check Environment Variables:
verify environment variable  CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED , ORDERER_CA, CC_NAME, CHANNEL_NAME, PEER1_ORG2_CA are correctly set in your environment.
you can check them by printing ENV variables
echo "CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=${CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED}"
echo "ORDERER_CA=${ORDERER_CA}"
echo "CC_NAME=${CC_NAME}"
echo "CHANNEL_NAME=${CHANNEL_NAME}"
echo "PEER1_ORG2_CA=${PEER1_ORG2_CA}"

